# Web Services that connect to PostgreSql

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, postgresql, json.net

I'm creating an iPhone app that has a DB in PostgreSql. I want to create web services that connect to the database and fetch the data in and out, like for example , I want to create a web service for the login screen of my iPhone app that would connect to the PostgreSql database and authenticate the user.

How do I go about with the web services part..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this question is destined to be closed, but before it is locked, I'll try to provide some direction. You can use any of your listed technologies to publish a web service. ASP.NET is my technology of most comfort, so might I recommend looking at using a simple web application with an exposed Page method, and using Npgsql as the database interface.

Using a simple page method isn't the most robust solution, but it will serve simple needs and requires very little specialized knowledge nor a WCF implementation, which can be daunting for some.